# Meteor Accounts.createUser not sending verification email

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor accounts core package to create new users and send them verification email, but I am facing a problem as when I call Accounts.createUser from server side as a method, no verification email is sent, however if I called Accounts.createUser from the client side new accounts are created and a verification link is sent to the client...can someone please tell me what I might be missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

```
Accounts.createUser({email: adminData.email, password : adminData.password});
```

Answer (score 4):

So some clues and tips. Normally `Accounts.createUser` will not sent out verification emails and that it does that in one case (client side) and not in the other case (server side) is a little strange. Normally it would only sent out verification emails when you have

```
Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
});
```

on the server side (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config). So first you should check that and maybe that already solves your problem.

When this isn't set the only other way an verification email got sent out should be calling `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendverificationemail) but this is only possible server side. So to make use of that client side you would need to write a server side method with it and call that via `Meteor.call` from the client side. However if you can't find your problem you could also use that to work around it by using `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` within `Accounts.onCreateUser` (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) on the server side. Or after you call `Accounts.createUser` server side as at that point you already know the users email address and the account already got created so that should work really well.

Oh and obviously the email package needs to be installed (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email) but as some mails already get sent out I guess that's the case.

Comment: You can't call `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` inside `Accounts.onCreateUser` because the user hasn't been created yet in that method. It will throw an exception, saying the user doesn't exist. However, a workaround is to do `Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id); }, 1000);` inside `Accounts.onCreateUser`. It's a bit hackish, but it waits until the user is created and then sends the email.

Comment: Another hackish workaround which avoids timeouts (which can always lead to problems ;-)) would be to use `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(loginAttempt){ ... }));`. Meteor fires it immediately after a complete registration and via `loginAttempt.user.emails[0].verified` (if it is present) you can check if the user already has a verified e-mail. Depending on the result you can do your stuff.

Comment: You can correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that send a repeat email every time they log in if they still haven't verified their email? Maybe this would work if you set some kind of flag after the first login, but checking verified might not be the best way.

Comment: Obviously setting a flag as first step in the "do your stuff"-section would be a good idea in most cases. But writing down so much details of the possible implementations after checking if a user still has unverified addresses would have been a bit long for a stackoverflow comment ;-)